# What does 'state of grace' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link but couldn't understand it: [vocabulary.com State of Grace](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/state%20of%20grace)

The context:

> Descriptions, prescriptions, and theories about improving teamwork often miss the deeper secrets and mysteries of how groups and teams reach the elusive **state of grace** and peak performance. Former Visa CEO Dee Hock captured the heart of the issue: “In the field of group endeavor, you will see incredible events in which the group performs far beyond the sum of its individual talents. It happens in the symphony, in the ballet, in the theater, in sports, and equally in business. It is easy to recognize and impossible to define. It is a mystique. It cannot be achieved without immense effort, training, and cooperation, but effort, training, and cooperation alone rarely create it” (quoted in Schlesinger, Eccles, and Gabarro, 1983, p. 173).

Source:[Reframing Organizations: Artistry, Choice, and Leadership](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iRArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA266&lpg=PA266&dq=Descriptions,%20prescriptions,%20and%20theories%20about%20improving%20teamwork%20often%20miss%20the%20deeper%20secrets%20and%20mysteries%20of%20how%20groups%20and%20teams%20reach%20the%20elusive%20state%20of%20grace%20and%20peak%20performance.&source=bl&ots=oxN2vcCgZO&sig=ACfU3U2eRMEO9JKVZlG-02INpxbSlldNbA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLgNeMw-bhAhVxKqYKHRcSChQQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Descriptions%2C%20prescriptions%2C%20and%20theories%20about%20improving%20teamwork%20often%20miss%20the%20deeper%20secrets%20and%20mysteries%20of%20how%20groups%20and%20teams%20reach%20the%20elusive%20state%20of%20grace%20and%20peak%20performance.&f=false), p. 266 *(Google Books link)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*State of grace* is a term borrowed from the Christian religion.

It means to be free of sin in a religious sense.

As a metaphor, here, it just means a state of having achieved such a high level.
Presumably, in order to be successful, teams working together need to reach a high spiritual level, in a lay sense, not a religious sense. Basically, mindfulness, another way to say it in today's more contemporary terminology.

[state of grace (it is not only Catholic by the way)](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36634)